# ScrollView in my .xml file is making the dropdown navigation toolbar nonresponsive

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollview

So, I am trying to make a daily task activity for my application, sort of like a planner. I want to be able to scroll down, but putting scroll view around my textview and edit text boxes makes my navigation dropdown unclickable. If I put the toolbar inside the scrollview all disaster occurs, and if I don't have the RelativeLayout inbetween the scrollview and the block of widgets, they don't sit where they should. Basically, I'm a little lost and I just want this to work. Is there another way to get a page to scroll? Anyway, here's what I have in my .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.myfinalprototype.WeeklyTasks">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/monday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="Monday"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mondayTasks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/monday"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter tasks here"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.EditText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tuesday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mondayTasks"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Tuesday"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tuesdayTasks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tuesday"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter tasks here"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.EditText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wednesday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tuesdayTasks"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Wednesday"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/wednesdayTasks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/wednesday"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter tasks here"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.EditText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thursday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/wednesdayTasks"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Thursday"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/thursdayTasks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thursday"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter tasks here"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.EditText" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thursdayTasks"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Friday"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fridayTasks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/friday"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter tasks here"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.EditText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saturday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fridayTasks"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Saturday"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/saturdayTasks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/saturday"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter tasks here"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.EditText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sunday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/saturdayTasks"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Sunday"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sundayTasks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sunday"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter tasks here"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.EditText" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```